# Bad width of head of longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}rrrrrrr@{}} \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{c}{Vertical} \\
    $i$
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\langle x^1_{i}, y^1_{i} \rangle$}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\langle x^2_{i}, y^2_{i} \rangle$}
      & $\measuredangle_{i}$ & $m_{i}$ \endhead \midrule
        $1$
    &   $\langle 17.90,$ & $27.19 \rangle$
    &   $\langle -192.10,$ & $69.53 \rangle$
    &   $-90.0°$
    &   $29$ \\
        $2$
    &   $\langle 47.65,$ & $31.32 \rangle$
    &   $\langle -162.35,$ & $73.66 \rangle$
    &   $-90.0°$
    &   $21$ \\
        $3$
    &   $\langle 85.94,$ & $32.43 \rangle$
    &   $\langle -124.06,$ & $74.77 \rangle$
    &   $-90.0°$
    &   $27$ \\
        $4$
    &   $\langle 117.53,$ & $34.29 \rangle$
    &   $\langle -92.47,$ & $76.63 \rangle$
    &   $-90.0°$
    &   $23$ \\
        $5$
    &   $\langle 154.71,$ & $29.83 \rangle$
    &   $\langle -55.29,$ & $72.17 \rangle$
    &   $-90.0°$
    &   $21$ \\
   \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{Average}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{r}{$\tilde{m} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}$} = $24.0$ \\ \bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Bad width of head of longtable]

The obvious problem is that header columns are misaligned. `$i$` should be above the numbers (first column) and `$m_i$` should be above the last column.

Comment: You need to compile two or three times in order that the header and footer of the `longtable` can be typeset with the correct lengths. As an aside: I'd put the first `\midrule` before `\endhead` (with ``\\`` in front of it).

Comment: As egerg says you need multiple runs -- this actually needs three runs to stabilize.

Comment: I ran it twice. But now I tried to run it three times and the problem is gone. Sorry, it was a very dumb question. Is it possible that I will ever need to run it four times?

Comment: A typographically suggestion: Use `{@{}rr@{${},{}$}rr@{${},{}$}rrr@{}}` as column specification and remove the commas in the table body.

Comment: @nagylzs TeX informs you if the `longtable` is not yet stable. Don't worry too much: during document preparation, you run frequently LaTeX, so this is a minor problem.

Comment: With the suggested column specification, it looks much better.

I guess I should not delete the aux file every time I run xetex...

Comment: The reason for the `.aux` file is to remember "stuff" for the next run.

Comment: How do you do multiple runs?

Comment: it can take an arbitrary number of runs but the message at the end of the run tells you every time whether another run is needed. (the same is true of \label/ref even without longtable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The headers and footers of a `longtable` cannot be typeset correctly at the first run, but also the rows: for saving memory and avoiding overflows, `longtable` processes the table dividing it into chunks and annotating in the `.aux` file the column widths, so that in the next LaTeX run they can be fixed.

Depending on the table, two or three runs may be needed. If a new run is needed, LaTeX will print in the `.log` file a couple of warnings. The first

```
Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed
(longtable)                in table 1 on input line 55.
```

when the table is typeset, the second

```
Package longtable Warning: Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.
```

at the end of the run. In this way the user is informed about the problem.

This shows also the importance of the `.aux` file that *mustn't* be deleted after a run, because it contains basic information for the next run (cross references, for instance). Only in a few cases, due to some kinds of errors in the input, the `.aux` file can become corrupt. This usually shows with weird errors in the early stages of the LaTeX run. When the compiler raises a very weird error, one of the strategies is indeed removing the `.aux` file; but this is more the exception than the rule.