# Table widths have changed - rerun LaTeX

Tags: tables, longtable

I have an application which stores LaTeX documents, and then (when the user clicks on a link) renders them into PDF files to be downloaded or viewed.

This works well in general, but I'm running into a small problem. Sometimes (it's not totally clear to me under what circumstances this happens), when a file is rendered with `pdflatex`, a warning will be issued:

`Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.`

And the resulting PDF, although rendered, will be incorrect (namely, column headers seem to be mis-aligned relative to the actual body columns of the table. Doing as the warning instructs, and running `pdflatex` a second time on the input file, renders the PDF completely correctly (everything aligned properly), with no warnings.

As an example, here is a table which exhibits this problem:

```
\begin{longtabu}{ r r r r r }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Available}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Billed}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Current}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Remaining}} \\
\endhead
1 - Foo & \$1,791.04 & \$0.00 &
    \$1,567.16 & \$223.88 \\
2 - Bar & \$58,730.01 & \$0.00 &
    \$19,579.01 & \$39,151.00 \\
Baz & \$6,839.00 & \$0.00 &
    \$0.00 & \$6,839.00 \\
\hline
\textbf{Profit} & \textbf{\$14,255.48} & \textbf{\$0.00} &
    \textbf{\$2,581.85} & \textbf{\$11,673.63} \\
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{\$145,055.13} &
    \textbf{\$0.00} & \textbf{\$25,032.69} & \textbf{\$120,022.44} \\
\end{longtabu}
```

I suppose there are two ways to answer my question:

- Am I causing this warning by giving `pdflatex` some "smelly" input? If so, how should I adjust my code to avoid this issue?
- Is there some way to tell `pdflatex`, "just re-run yourself if needed, don't tell me about it"? The naive solution to this issue would be to just detect this warning and then re-run `pdflatex`, but this seems like a very messy way to solve my problem.

It seems that, from e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74681/bad-width-of-head-of-longtable), these repeated runs may simply be necessary. In this case, I'd like to make `pdflatex` do it automatically, rather than having to run it by hand two or more times.

Comment: that's all standard behaviour of the longtable package. If you use a controlling application such as make or latexmk or arara or emacs or... then _it_ can read the log file for you and re-run latex but latex itself can't

Comment: That's the impression I was getting from reading other questions, but I figured it was worth confirming it before I alter my controlling application to try to detect this situation. Thanks! :) You should add this as an answer.

Comment: note there is nothing really special about longtable, tables of contents, cross references with \ref, indexes, all require latex to be run more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's all standard behaviour of the longtable package. If you use a controlling application such as make or latexmk or arara or emacs or... then it can read the log file for you and re-run latex but latex itself can't.

Note there is nothing really special about longtable, tables of contents, cross references with `\ref`, indexes, all require latex to be run more than once.