# Bad width of head of longtable, persistant

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, multicolumn

My problem is almost identical to the one in [question 74681](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74681/bad-width-of-head-of-longtable), but with a notable exception: I can run latex for a 1000 times or more, it will still say "Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX". A minimum test case to reproduce this is here:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}[c]{r|r|l|l|X|r|r}
    pos. &
    date &
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{quantity} &
    description &
    item price &
    net price
\endhead
\endlastfoot
    1 &
    02.10. &
    1 &
    piece &
    testitem testitem &
    50,00 E per piece &
    50,00 E
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\LTXtable{17cm}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the problem is gone if I change the word "quantity" to either something shorter (e.g. "qty.") **or** to something longer (e.g. "quantity quantity"), but this is of course not a solution for the generic case (actually files like this are processed automatically and the message "Rerun LaTeX" should trigger a rerun of LaTeX which would trigger an endless loop right now).

I hope this can't be simply bad luck - but what did I miss?

Edit: Unfortunately, the problem still persists. Today it hit me within a document I could reduce to

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{\mathord\mathcomma}{#1} }

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}[c]{r|r@{\,}l|X}
    date            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{quanti}   & description           \\      
                    &               &               &                       \kill   
\endhead
\endlastfoot
                    & 2             & units         & some descriptive text \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\LTXtable{13cm}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

Note the kill-ed line in the header as suggested - but the columns still don't match (with the difference being much bigger in the original). What to do now?

Comment: Why do you have an extra column specified which you don't use? And why is `d` applied to a column which only contains a single integer?

Comment: Real bad luck, I'd say.

Comment: @cfr these were remainders of the (by far more complex) original, sorry. I removed them now.

Comment: 17cm is wider than textwidth so this table can not work (it would be better if it didn't loop forever but what output do you want for this input)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added `\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}` so the textwidth is much wider than 17cm, the problem remains.

Comment: @egreg so who can I blame?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Choose between the authors of `longtable` and `ltxtable`.

Comment: @egreg: Perfectly right! I've deleted my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

er it's a hidden feature sorry. A simple workaround is to make sure that your headings don't end with a multicolumn row (for example by adding a `\kill` row)

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{\mathord\mathcomma}{#1} }

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}[c]{r|r|d{1}|l|X|r|r|r}
    pos. &
    date &
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{quantity} &
    description &
    item price &
    net price
    \\
&&&&&&\kill
\endhead
    1 &
    02.10. &
    1 &
    piece &
    testitem testitem &
    50,00 E per piece &
    50,00 E
     \\

\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\rule{17cm}{1cm}\end{center}

\LTXtable{17cm}{\jobname.ltxtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what I am doing here... but it works. Thanks.

Comment: An update to the documentation that unhides the bug, er, feature is needed.

Comment: @egreg no point in documenting it, if I do anything I'll remove the feature.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately, the problem popped up again (like shown in the second example)

Comment: @SlowFox hmm need to think about that, seems like a fundamental flaw in ltxtable's logic;-) mostly around the code documented with the not very encouraging comment `% |\multicolum| A sad tale, For now just stop |longtable| messing with it, so that |tabularx| can mess with it.`  If you add more text the problem may just go on its own accord, or you could try `ltablex` package instead (a different merger of tabularx and longtable) or to be honest in a hand written document (as opposed to automated database dumps) I would just use `longtable` with fixed size `p` columns that I choose by hand.

Comment: @SlowFox sorry, thanks for the nicely constructed test file, if I think of anything I'll ping here.